# How to overwrite workbook file with Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

My code is as simple as below. I just create a xlsx workbook, save it to a file. Then I reopen it from the file, make some changes and try to overwrite it.

```
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    wb.createSheet("test");

    wb.write(new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx"));
    wb.close();

    // works fine until this point

    wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("file.xlsx"));
    wb.createSheet("test2");

    // fails with "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream"
    wb.write(new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx"));
    // wb.write(new FileOutputStream("file2.xlsx")); // works fine and creates both files
    wb.close();
```

The initial creation of the file goes ok. I tested pausing the code and opened the file in Excel to make sure it's valid.

I can open the recently created file and make changes. The problem happens on overwrite (`wb.write`). I get `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`. The file becomes 0 byte.

Strangely, if I do `wb.write(new FileOutputStream("file2.xlsx"));` instead of `wb.write(new FileOutputStream("file.xlsx"));` everything works fine. Both files `file.xlsx` and `file2.xlsx` are created and have the changes applied. This was pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52895346/2761418).

Also, the problem is not about opened streams or such. Because if I execute only the second part of the code after the file already exists and is valid it also fails.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146161/apache-poi-fileinputstream-works-file-object-fails-nullpointerexception/46149469#46149469. One cannot use a `File` to create a `Workbook` and then overwrite the same file. Do using a `FileInputstream` instead of a `File`.

Comment: I works fine now. I can't believe apache poi never fixed such a basic, broken and old thing. I doubt they even consider it to be broken.